# Javascript codewars : Tribonacci Sequence

Tags: javascript

```js
function tribonacci(signature, n) {
  var myArray = [];
  var lenArray = 0;
  var i = 0;
  var outPut = 0;
  var x = 0;


  if (n > 0) {
    while (i < 3) {
      myArray.push(signature[i]);
      i++;
    }
    lenArray = myArray.length - 1;
    i = 0;
    while (lenArray < n) {

      while (x < 3) {
        var v = x + i;
        outPut += myArray[v];
        x++;
      }
      i++;
      lenArray = myArray.length - 1;
      myArray.push(outPut);
    }
    return myArray;
  } else {
    return [];
  };
}

console.log(tribonacci([1, 1, 1], 10));
```

First, I tried to push first 3 items into "myArray".
Second, in the "while" loop, while it's less than "n" (number of items needed to be in the array), add the last 3 items in "myArray" until "myArray" reaches the needed "n" amount.

e.g. tribonacci([1,1,1],10)
Return should be [1,1,1,3,5,9,17,31,57,105]
Adding the last 3 items continuously until it reaches 10 items in an array.

Instead I get as result:
[1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]

I have no idea why it's stuck on 3s.
I tried "i++" below the 2nd "while" loop so that it can start adding the last 3 items every time "myArray" grows by one, but that doesn't seem to be the issue. Is the "outPut" being stuck on 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var v = x + i;` uses `x` to calculate the correct index.

After adding those 3 numbers, `x` needs to be reset.

Also, `outPut` is reused in the next iteration, but it keeps adding values, so your output will get to high. This needs to be reset to `0` after the 3-loop.

Add `outPut = x = 0` after pushing `outPut` into `myArray`

```js
function tribonacci(signature, n) {
  var myArray = [];
  var lenArray = 0;
  var i = 0;
  var outPut = 0;
  var x = 0;


  if (n > 0) {
    while (i < 3) {
      myArray.push(signature[i]);
      i++;
    }
    lenArray = myArray.length - 1;
    i = 0;
    while (lenArray < n) {

      while (x < 3) {
        var v = x + i;
        outPut += myArray[v];
        x++;
      }
      i++;
      
      lenArray = myArray.length - 1;
      myArray.push(outPut);
      outPut = x = 0
    }
    return myArray;
  } else {
    return [];
  };
}

console.log(tribonacci([1, 1, 1], 10));
```

---

```json
[
  1,
  1,
  1,
  3,
  5,
  9,
  17,
  31,
  57,
  105,
  193,
  355
]
```

---

Some bonus-tips to improve the readabilty:

- Use (`...`) spread operator to replace the first `while`:
  `var myArray = [ ...signature ];`
- Use `myArray.length - 1` instead off defining a variable with the same value
- Use `myArray[x + i]` instead off defining another varible
- Return on `n < 0` to you don't need to intent that much

Applying those will give:

```js
function tribonacci(signature, n) {
    var myArray = [ ...signature ];
    var i = 0;
    var x = 0;
    var outPut = 0;

    if (n < 0) {
        return [];
    }

    while ((myArray.length - 1) < n) {
        while (x < 3) {
            outPut += myArray[x + i];
            x++;
        }
        i++;

        myArray.push(outPut);
        outPut = x = 0;
    }
    
    return myArray;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I forgot to reset my var. lol.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there are you doing this for homework on `while` loops? If so refer to @0stone0 's answer which solves it right!

If on the other hand you want to dive into JS a little more, I'd suggest you a more coincise solution with some cool `Array` function:

```
function tribonacci(signature, size) {
    const output = signature;
  while(output.length < size) {
    output.push(output.slice(-3).sum());
  }
  return output;
}

console.log({ result: tribonacci([1, 1, 1], 10) });
```

Some version of JS don't include the `Array.sum` function which would be something like this:

```
Array.prototype.sum = function() {
    return this.reduce((sum, curr) => sum + curr, 0);
}
```